# Oracle order by different

Tags: java, oracle, sorting, sql-order-by, mybatis

I have a table in an Oracle Database like this

```
ID   | LABEL
------------
 1   |  label alpha 1
 2   |  label alpha 2
 3   |  label alpha a
```

when I do a select in an application like Squirrel like this :

```
select * FROM MA_TABLE order by LABEL asc
```

I get :

```
ID   | LABEL
------------
 1   |  label alpha 1
 2   |  label alpha 2
 3   |  label alpha a
```

which is fine !

but When I execute the same request using MyBatis :

```
<select id="selectMaTable" resultMap="resultMap" >
  Select * FROM MA_TABLE order by LABEL asc
</select>
```

I get :

```
ID   | LABEL
------------
 3   |  label alpha a
 1   |  label alpha 1
 2   |  label alpha 2
```

The alphabetic characters come before the numeric characters... why ??

thanks in advance,

Antoine

Ps : I am using org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.0.5 and com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.2.0 for database access

Edit :
[this linked help me a bit also](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d228206/bases-donnees/oracle/administration)

Thanks to Soulcheck's remark, I found that if I change the order by clause with ORDER BY NLSSORT(ATL_SIT.ATL_SIT_LIB, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY') it works...

Does anyone knows how to force NLS_SORT=BINARY with myBatis ?
(It is already set on my Oracle database in NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it might be a locale issue. Connect with squirrel and check what `NLS_LANG` it sets, then check what locale uses your java app. Another parameter that can influence sort is `NLS_SORT`.

You can check the value of both by issuing:

```
select parameter,value from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS where parameter in('NLS_LANGUAGE','NLS_SORT');
```

Then you can test it in java by using:

```
Locale.getDefault()
```

and set it by using:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale)
```

or by adding jvm parameters:

```
-Duser.country=en -Duser.language=en
```

**edit**

[spring forums](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?109756-Best-way-to-set-NLS_SORT-for-Oracle) recommend creating a logon trigger which sets NLS_SORT environmental variable on user logon. It's not MyBatis, but jdbc anyway so should work in your case.

Comment: That seemed to be a good guess, thanks! but my NLS_LANGUAGE is 'AMERICAN' and my 'NLS_SORT' is 'BINARY'. Still, I tried to change the Locale in the java program (FR, EN, ...) but the result is still the same... any other idea?

Comment: changing the ORDER BY statement with ORDER BY NLSSORT(LABEL, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY') make it works! but I don't want to change every order by request of my program... maybe someone know some MyBatis parameter that help changing that ??

Comment: thank you ! I will use this solution for now. But I am still trying to find another way to do that using datasource parameter in spring. If I found anything else, I'll post-it here