# Order by different results

Tags: java, jpa, sql-order-by, openjpa

Hey i have a problem but i cant explain it myself.
I use OpenJPA and have a simple class:

```
@Entity
public class Organisation implements Serializable{
@Id
private int id;
private String name;    

public Organisation(int id, String name){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}   
}
```

I add the organisation with names aa, bb, AA, BB and query it with:

```
TypedQuery<Organisation> qry = em.createQuery("select o from Organisation o order by o.name", Organisation.class);
```

**EDIT:** This is all the same WAR and database:
On Glassfish i get: **aa, AA, bb, BB**
On Websphere i get: **AA,BB,aa,bb**
On Oracle directly SQL-Query i get: **aa, AA, bb, BB**

I test it at home with glassfish/h2 and i get **AA,BB,aa,bb**

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA doesn't do anything special with the ordering, it just generates the ORDER BY clause that gets passed to the database, so it's almost assuredly an issue with the database.  Are you using a different database, or different connection parameters in the cases where you see different results?  If the collation settings are different in the different scenarios you could see something like this.

Edit 1:

This other Stack Overflow question appears to resolve this issue:

[stackoverflow.com/questions/8818201/oracle-order-by-different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818201/oracle-order-by-different)

Comment: i edit my first post.... Glassfish and Websphere access on the same database with the same war. And the query/created query is the same, too.

Comment: Sorry.. my answer probably should have been a comment. :)  What database are you using with Glassfish and Websphere?  Oracle, presumably?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818201/oracle-order-by-different might help you.

Comment: i cant try it at the moment, but i looks like my problem, thanks :)